# if $\frac{a}{b}$ divides $\frac{c}{d}$, and $gcd(a,b)=gcd(c,d)=1,$ then does $b = d$?

Tags: linear-algebra, rational-numbers, gcd-and-lcm

I'm having issues trying to simplify finding a "lower multiple". Essentially I'd like to be able to develop a short method to solve the following statement:

Assume you have two rational numbers, **r1** and **r2**. You can also assume that

1)$$r1=\frac ab, \space r2=\frac cd,\space for\space some\space a, b, c, d \in \mathbb Z (where \space b,d \neq 0)$$ 
2) $$ gcd(a,b) = gcd(c,d) = 1$$ and r1, r2 are simplified into their lowest terms

If **r1** | **r2**, does b = d?

EDIT: After the multiplication has taken place, I don't want a' = c' and b' = d' after simplification.

BONUS: would b always be a multiple of d? (or vice versa). I wonder if the numerators sharing prime factors and denominators sharing prime factors has anything to do with it.

I've tried using my first/second year linear algebra proof methods but I can't seem to find a theorem that helps. I've drawn up a couple of examples and found it true, but I'm also biased because I probably want it to be true. If anyone knows a counterexample to this, could they please point it out?

Comment: Does $r_1|r_2$ mean that there exists some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ with $kr_1=r_2$? Because divisibility is usally defined for integers, not rational numbers. And if $k\in\mathbb{Q}$, your statement becomes immediatly false.

Comment: Your question is correct, I would like k to be an integer

Comment: Well....$\frac 12=3\times \frac 16$ would appear to be a counterexample, no?

Comment: if \frac { r_2}{r_1} is an integer then $ad|bc \implies a|c$ and $d|b$

Comment: @lulu (I updated the question) I would like k*r1 $\neq$ r2

Comment: I'm sorry, you want $kr_1=r_2$ and $kr_1\neq r_2$?  What does that mean?

Comment: bad wording, I mean after the multiplication has taken place, I don't want a' = c' and b' = d' after simplification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counter example: $$\frac{3}{8} | \frac{9}{4}$$

Comment: hmmm, I"ll edit the question, I meant to say that the rationals are simplified in their lowest terms

Comment: How would you like to simplify the ones I just provided?

Comment: would b always be a multiple of d? (or vice versa)

Comment: You might try a proof by contradiction for that.

Comment: In your example, 3 and 9 share a prime factor, as do 8 and 4, so I'm wondering if that plays a part?